# How can I find an $x$ in terms of $n$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^x}{3^k-5} \geq r$ for some $r \in [0, \infty)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

How can I solve this inequality for $x$ in terms of $n$ such that $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^x}{3^k-5} \geq r$$ 
for some $r \in [0, \infty)$?

Comment: Numerically (Newton's, Bisection, ...) . $f(x)$ is increasing so as long as $f(0)$ is not greater than r you will get a unique solution.

Comment: Is there a way to do it algebraiclly?

Comment: No method sorry. Very few equations can be solved algebraically.